# Solving CORS issues when calling fetch from React App

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, cors, fetch

I'm trying to send http requests from my React client app to a RestfulApi (built with Spring), but I'm facing CORS issues.

As I understand it to solve cors issue there are several ways, 2 of them that I know:

1) Install a CORS extension on your browser (your browser will be exposed to security risks, but if it's only during development and it can be enabled/disabled then I can live with it)

2) Allow headers from your server rest API- I found a spring annotation called @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring-mvc-cors-configuration/

Using the first approach:

First call that I perform is GET login request and it works, but I'm getting back an empty response with empty headers!

Second call is another GET request to get some projects details, but I'm getting 401!

From some investigation I understood that there is a need to send the browser sessionId (stored in cookies) and pass it to the HTTP request as param in order to be authorized... but didn't manage yet making it works.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I reached this page:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

Adding another class to my rest server app didn't help as well:

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
        http.cors();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your react code working, I mean on your localhost?
cors plugins works only when your code is working on localhost

Comment: The client app is on local host, yes. Server side can be localhost (with different port of course) or other host.

Comment: If you are using CRA (create-react-app) you might also want to give proxying a look - https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development, I've used that a lot during projects development.

Comment: SOLVED: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973215/cors-unauthorized-401-error-when-calling-spring-rest-api/56989449#56989449

Answer (score 1):

> Install a CORS extension on your browser (your browser will be exposed to security risks, but if it's only during development and it can be enabled/disabled then I can live with it)

CORS extensions tend to just inject `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers into responses.

They don't do everything else that needs to be done to enable CORS.

In particular, they tend not to handle the preflight requests that need before credentials can be sent in a request. So:

1. the browser sends a preflight request asking for permission to make a request with credentials
2. the server responds with an *Unauthorized* error because the credentials weren't sent
3. the extension injects `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers
4. the browser denied access to the response to the JS because the response had an *Unauthorised* status (the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers not being sufficient to override that)

Implement a real solution when you need CORS. Browser extensions are a waste of time because the will need replacing with real solutions in the end and only work in a subset of cases in the first place.

Comment: OK I agree. I disabled the extension, removed the setUpProxy from my project (another approach for solving CORS) and implemented the second approach on server, but again I pass the login (but getting empty headers in response) and failing on 401. I was attempting to take the set-cookies parts from response of login first call in order to send it as parameter to the second call and get over the 401 error. Am I on the right direction?